# adding items to new collection instead of replacing whole collection

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm using Automapper and I'm wondering if it is possible to add all the items in a collection on a source to the destination.

Consider the following:

```
public class A { public IDictionary<int, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>(); }

public class B { public IDictionary<int, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>(); }
```

Then you create the mappings:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>();
```

And do the actually mapping:

```
Mapper.Map<A, B>(instanceOfA);
```

I believe that behind the screens this will happen:

```
newInstanceOfB.myDictionary = instanceOfA.myDictionary
```

But is it possible to tell Automapper to do this (maybe with a custom converter of something...):

```
foreach (var item in instanceOfA.myDictionary)
    newInstanceOfB.myDictionary[item.Key] = item.Value
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to work for me

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>()
     .ForMember(d => d.myDictionary, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(
                s => s.myDictionary.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)));
```

Here is the complete sample

```
public class A { public IDictionary<int, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>(); }
public class B { public IDictionary<int, string> myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>(); }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var instanceOfA = new A
                              {
                                  myDictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
                                                     {
                                                         {1, "a"},
                                                         {2, "b"}
                                                     }
                              };
        Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>()
            .ForMember(d => d.myDictionary, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(
              s => s.myDictionary.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value)));
        var instanceOfB = Mapper.Map<A, B>(instanceOfA);
        instanceOfA.myDictionary[1] = "c";

        if (instanceOfB.myDictionary[1] == "c")
            Console.WriteLine("Failed");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Succeeded");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**Edit after comments:**
**Edited again **

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>()
   .ForMember(d => d.myDictionary, opt => opt.Ignore())
   .AfterMap((s, d) =>
                      {
                       d.myDictionary.Clear();
                       s.myDictionary.ToList().ForEach(p => d.myDictionary.Add(p));
                   });
```

Comment: Hi boca,
thanks for your reply but it doesn't do the trick. I'm mapping an DTO object to an Domain object from NHibernate. The AutoMapper changes not only the items in the collection but also the collection itself. If I ignore the collection in the mapping and add/remove the items from one object to another manually (with a foreach i.e.) it works fine. I was just wondering if you can do this within the Automapper but I'm guessing it can't be done :-(

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. In my answer I was able to map the collection creating new items. I don't see why this wouldn't work for a DTO and an Nhibernate entity. You can do it with ResolveUsing as I did above, or you can ignore it like you said, and do the mapping with an AfterMap clause

Comment: Correct but in the example the hashcode of myDictionary of class B has changed by Automapper, because it always returns a new dictionary (I've checked to source code ;-)). And so NHibernate won't save the domain object because it sees that the original dictionary is changed. I've managed to solve the issue by making a helper method that starts with an Automapper map and afterwards does the copying of the items through reflection.

Comment: I see the issue now. I know you already solved this, but here is my final suggestion (I also added it to the answer)                                               Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>()
      .ForMember(d => d.myDictionary, opt => opt.Ignore())
      .AfterMap((s, d) => s.myDictionary.ToList().ForEach(p => d.myDictionary.Add(p)));

Comment: Hi boca, thanks for all the help! You have to clear the destination dictionary before but you gave me the ideas i needed! Mapper.CreateMap<A, B>() .ForMember(d => d.myDictionary, opt => opt.Ignore()).AfterMap((s,d) => d.MyDictionary.Clear()).AfterMap((s, d) => s.myDictionary.ToList().ForEach(p => d.myDictionary.Add(p)));

Comment: Good point. I have edited the answer again to include the clear. If this was helpful, would you mind accepting my answer? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for this, your *edited again* comment helped me to get this working for my KeyedCollection properties.

Comment: +1. I have been trying to avoid doing ForMember(...Ignore()) then AfterMap(...), but after trying lots of options my sad conclusion is that there is no other way. Defining value or type resolvers for the mapping won't help (as they force you to replace the collection anyway). Ahhh, this is such a pain!

Comment: +1 Thanks for this answer. Doing `opt.Ignore()` followed by `.AfterMap()` isn't very intuitive but it did the job for me where I want to append to a string property (instead of overwrite) in my destination object.